# An error with Mockito eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Has anyone faced the following issue with Mockito before:

```
Failed to use Mockito on interface java.util.Enumeration: 
ClassCastException occurred while creating the mockito mock :
  class to mock : 'java.util.Enumeration', loaded by classloader : 'null'
  created class : 'codegen.java.util.Enumeration$MockitoMock$1372797153', loaded by classloader : 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@10084611'
  proxy instance class : 'codegen.java.util.Enumeration$MockitoMock$1372797153', loaded by classloader : 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@10084611'
  instance creation by : ObjenesisInstantiator
```

The weird thing is I face this issue only when I run the project with Eclipse but not with the command line.

Comment: Can you show us the code you want to mock please.

Comment: Post some code which creates the issue.